# Аналог API Guide

Tags: winapi

Существует ли современный аналог API Guide? Тот не обновлялся с 2002 года и в нем нет специфичных функций Vista и Seven, вроде DWM.
UPD:
Нашел ApiViewer, он конечно поновее, и на C# код выдает, но все равно не то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть AddIn для Visual Studio от [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/), сам пользовался, вещь хорошая.
Информация о функциях итд. грузится с их сайта, где она постоянно обновляется. (функции DWM API там есть).

Единственное: AddIn был выпущен для VS 2003/2005, поэтому, чтобы его установить в 2008/2010, нужно подкрутить его ручками.

Для установки в VS 2008 описание есть [здесь](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/GeneralContent?c=knowledgebase%5CPInvoke%5CKB200711000198.htm). Для 2010 думаю по аналогии..

Comment: Я так понимаю, к VC# 2008 Express прикрутить особо не получится :) Тогда к VS 2010.

Прикрутилось идеально, спасибо